# DateTimeFormatter Validation for Existing Year, Optional Month, and Optional Day

Tags: java, java-time, datetimeformatter

We are attempting to write a single DateTimeFormatter that helps us validate an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) that allows our end user's to enter just a year, a year and a month, or a year, month, and day.  We also want to validate the entered date actually exists.

In the following code there are two examples of dates and date validation acting funky.  The first is a validation test for just year with an optional month.  Which doesn't properly validate a month of '00'.

The second example shows a test (NOT) failing on incorrect optional months value.

Any friendly direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

public class DateTimeFormatterForStackOverflowTest {

    @Test
    public void test_year_or_year_and_month_not_valid() {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("uuuu[-MM]")
                .toFormatter()
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

        this.expectException("1984-0", formatter, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        // Doesn't throw exception. 
        this.expectException("1984-00", formatter, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        // Doesn't throw exception.
        this.expectException("1984-13", formatter, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        // Doesn't throw exception.
        this.expectException("1984-99", formatter, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_year_or_year_month_or_year_month_day_not_valid() {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("[uuuu-MM-dd][uuuu-MM][uuuu]")
                .toFormatter()
                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);

        this.expectException("1984-0", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        // Doesn't throw exception.
        this.expectException("1984-00", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        // Doesn't throw exception.
        this.expectException("1984-13", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        // Doesn't throw exception.
        this.expectException("1984-99", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-00-01", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-13-01", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-01-0", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-01-00", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-01-32", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-12-00", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
        this.expectException("1984-12-32", formatter, LocalDate::from, YearMonth::from, Year::from);
    }

    private void expectException(String value, DateTimeFormatter formatter, TemporalQuery<?>... queries) {

        assertThrows(DateTimeParseException.class,
                () -> formatter.parseBest(value, queries));
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.time.format.DateTimeParseException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:3083)
    at DateTimeFormatterForStackOverflowTest.expectException(DateTimeFormatterForStackOverflowTest.java:59)
    at DateTimeFormatterForStackOverflowTest.test_year_or_year_month_or_year_month_day_not_valid(DateTimeFormatterForStackOverflowTest.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:185)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the output from your test into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we eventually did to solve our particular iso date validation issues.

First we created 5 different validators (one for each of the different iso date we accept) and each of those validators implemented the following interface:

```
package app.validation.type;

public interface IsoDateFormatValidator {

    boolean isValid(String date);
}
```

We then created a validator that would go through a list of iso date based validators to see if the entered date is valid.

```
package app.validation.type;

import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.List;

public class ValidIsoDateFormatValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidIsoDateFormat, String> {

    private final List<IsoDateFormatValidator> isoDateFormatValidatorList;

    public ValidIsoDateFormatValidator(List<IsoDateFormatValidator> isoDateFormatValidatorList) {
        this.isoDateFormatValidatorList = isoDateFormatValidatorList;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidIsoDateFormat annotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String inputDate, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        boolean valid = true;

        if (StringUtils.hasText(inputDate)) {

            valid = isoDateFormatValidatorList.stream()
                    .map(v -> v.isValid(inputDate))
                    .anyMatch((Boolean.TRUE::equals));
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Here are the individual iso date validators we used.

Date/Time YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
package app.validation.type;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;

public class IsoDateTimeFormatValidator implements IsoDateFormatValidator {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String date) {

        boolean valid = false;

        try {

            LocalDateTime ldt =  LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
            valid = true;

        } catch (DateTimeParseException ignored) {

        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Date/Time w/Milliseconds YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS

```
package app.validation.type;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

public class IsoDateTimeMillisFormatValidator implements IsoDateFormatValidator {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String date) {

        boolean valid = false;

        try {

            TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse(date);
            valid = true;

        } catch (DateTimeParseException ignored) {

        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Year YYYY

```
package app.validation.type;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

public class IsoYearFormatValidator implements IsoDateFormatValidator {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu")
            .toFormatter();

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String date) {

        boolean valid = false;

        try {

            TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse(date);
            valid = true;

        } catch (DateTimeParseException ignored) {

        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Year/Month YYYY/MM

```
package app.validation.type;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

public class IsoYearMonthFormatValidator implements IsoDateFormatValidator {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM")
            .toFormatter();

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String date) {

        boolean valid = false;

        try {

            TemporalAccessor ta = formatter.parse(date);
            valid = true;

        } catch (DateTimeParseException ignored) {

        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Year/Month/Day YYYY/MM/DD

```
package app.validation.type;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;

public class IsoYearMonthDayFormatValidator implements IsoDateFormatValidator {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd")
            .toFormatter()
            .withResolverStyle ( ResolverStyle.LENIENT );

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String date) {

        boolean valid = false;

        try {

            LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse (date, formatter);
            valid = true;

        } catch (DateTimeParseException ignored) {

        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Of course if you have other iso date/time required validations that aren't listed here, that could be added since the `ValidIsoDateFormatValidator` takes a list of `IsoDateFormatValidator`s.

Answer (score 4):

You can learn what’s happening by printing the type of the result of `parseBest`:

```
assertThrows(DateTimeParseException.class,
        () -> System.out.println(
            formatter.parseBest(value, queries).getClass()));
```

The result is:

```
java.time.Year
```

As you expected, "1984-00" cannot be parsed as a YearMonth.  But you passed `YearMonth::from, Year::from` as your TemporalQuerys, so after parseBest discovers that the string cannot be parsed using YearMonth.from, it tries again using Year.from, which succeeds.

Why does it succeed?  Because a Year only needs the year part (`uuuu` in your DateTimeFormatter) to be resolved.  No attempt is ever made to resolve the month, so the `00` is ignored.  It doesn’t matter to Year.from whether that part can be resolved to a valid month.

If I wanted to parse multiple types, and wanted to be sure the entire string is always valid, I would just use a simple approach:

```
public Temporal parse(String value) {
    String len = value.length();
    if (len == 4) {
        return Year.parse(value);
    } else if (len == 7) {
        return YearMonth.parse(value);
    } else {
        return LocalDate.parse(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer/comment.  I did notice we were getting a Year in other testing, but your comment explained why that was happening.  I think that I have an idea of how to actually solve this problem now, but it will take some work...  First I think we have to figure out if the actual format is right (using a non-strict DateTimeFormatter), if the format is right, then use a strict DateTimeFormatter to verify the date actually exists.  Does that seem right to you?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @hooknc Do you have to do it all with a single DateTimeFormatter?  I would just pick the direct approach:  `if (length == 4) temporal = Year.parse(value); else if (length == 7) temporal = YearMonth.parse(value); else temporal = LocalDate.parse(value);`

Comment: No, a single DateTimeFormatter is not a requirement.  We just like the simplicity.  But it does look like we'll be using multiple formatters to do the job.  I really appreciate your answer and feedback.  I'll post our answer when we get it working.